# How do I limit thumbnails size and life time?

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

how to limit thumbnails life time(maximum_age) and size(maximum_size) in ubuntu 12.04 with dconf? Or should I install gconf-editor to do this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what parameters would you change in either of those to limit the lifetime? I wasn't aware that there is such a configuration option. And which software does it configure to delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok. I've found it in dconf-editor  http://itmages.ru/image/view/723527/4294c4e2

In words, run `dconf-editor` in a terminal after installing `dconf-tools`. In the window that opens, click on `org`, `gnome`, `desktop`,`thumbnail-cache` and set the desired values.